# PHP: Trouble with tables in echo for a SELECT * FROM

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to style some tables I'm pulling from my database, I wished for the columns in the rows to be aligned towards the column names to make it more readable.

The only problem when trying to use PHP, I don't know what I've done wrong, I've attempted to create a table outside a while loop, that displays the names, and then start the table there, and then end the table inside the while loop. But I wish for all the rows to be as the first one, I tried changing css and moving the `echo "</table>";` and `echo "<table>";` but have no idea what I'm possibly doing wrong to make it look nice, or at least organized into a tableset, any ideas, or better ways I could do it to make it work and look organized?

I appreciate any help and comments, here the source and problem;

**Image:**
[image: Image of the output from the HTML/CSS in the source code, a given example of the code being run.]

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
include('connect_mysql.php');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM artist";
        $resultat = $conn->query($sql);
        echo"<table>";
        echo "<tr id='tabledesc'>";
                echo"<td class='tabledesc'>Artist Name</td>";
                echo"<td class='tabledesc'>Birthday</td>";
                echo"<td class='tabledesc'>Name</td>";
                echo"<td class='tabledesc'>Surname</td>";
                echo"<td class='tabledesc'>Country</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        while($rad = $resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
            $artist_id = $rad["artist_id"];
            $birthday = $rad["birthday"];
            $artistname = $rad["artistname"];
            $name = $rad["name"];
            $surname = $rad["surname"];
            $country = $rad["country"];

        echo "<div class='tableselect'>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo"<td class='tablerow'>$artistname</td>";
                echo"<td class='tablerow'>$birthday</td>";
                echo"<td class='tablerow'>$name</td>";
                echo"<td class='tablerow'>$surname</td>";
                echo"<td class='tablerow'>$country</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</div class='tableselect'>";

        }


        $conn->close();
?>
```

The A$AP Ferg column is clearly working as intended, but then the while loop stops producing the same rows given after the table, heres the **CSS I've put in:**

```
.tableselect {
font-size: 25px;
color: tomato;
}

table, td { 
font-size: 25px;
color: tomato;
}

.tabledesc {
text-align: center;
color: black;
}
```

I'm sorry for the halfway unclear question, but just lastly I will just give more insight. I'm creating a rap database where users can input an artist and information about them, here I just want to select all the rows and put them in like the first column printed as.. But unfortunately my code is slightly messy, and PHP is not my strong language :D

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Quick glance and I might be wrong, but `echo "<div class='tableselect'>";` in a `<table>` shouldn't be done? I thought only `<tr>`, `<td>`, `<thead>` and `<tbody>` were allowed within tables. https://css-tricks.com/using-divs-inside-tables/ Also you close the `<table>` element in every while loop.

Comment: As LOEK said above, you should be printing `<tr><td>...</td></tr>` not `<div>`

Comment: what  exactly do you what to do, ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML tags are mismatched; a `<div>` element cannot be a direct child of a `<table>` element and the closing `</table>` tag should not be within the loop body.

In my opinion it's also a bad idea to `echo` HTML code. Write HTML first and then open and close PHP tags as and when they are needed. I also find it much more convenient to use the alternative PHP syntax when mixing HTML with PHP.

Comment: You guys are truly amazing, I knew it was just an easy to fix syntax problem that I couldn't detect, I appreciate the warm help, and sorry for the slightly bad code, still learning ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your div have no place there, also since you opened your table outside the loop you should do the same when closing, remember in html last opening tag must be first closing tag, to give you a better understanding here's how it should be done (if your class tableselect gives some css to the entire row you should put it ion your tr tag):

```
 while($rad = $resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
        $artist_id = $rad["artist_id"];
        $birthday = $rad["birthday"];
        $artistname = $rad["artistname"];
        $name = $rad["name"];
        $surname = $rad["surname"];
        $country = $rad["country"];

    echo "<tr class='tableselect'>
            <td class='tablerow'>$artistname</td>
            <td class='tablerow'>$birthday</td>
            <td class='tablerow'>$name</td>
            <td class='tablerow'>$surname</td>
            <td class='tablerow'>$country</td>
          </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) also for changing my code around to prove the optimal! Its changed!

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid in several ways. You can't have a DIV inside of a table, you can't end a table more than once, and you can't include a class when closing a tab. Put the `echo "<div` line before the `echo "<table`, move the closing of both the table and div (which you have in the correct order) outside of your while loop, and get rid of `class='tableselect'` from your `</div>` tag.

Comment: When you do this, btw, you'll be able to remove your `table, td` styles, as they'll be redundant. You should also consider using `th` instead of `td` for the header row, so that things like search engines will understand your data better.

Comment: Your comment was also really helpful in the finding of the answer, thanks a lot, its working!